# Generalisation of prime numbers to matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Is it possible to generalise prime numbers to matrices? I'm trying to solve a Rubix cube in the minimum number of steps and I think this would be useful. I think it's possible to represent Rubix cube operations in the language of linear algebra or matrices. From there, maybe I can represent a solution of the Rubix cube as a product of matrices. Transforming a product of matrices into its minimum decomposition (this is where the prime version of matrices come in) should provide a 'minimum' solution.

**Disclosure:** this is just my intuition and I understand completely if what I just wrote doesn't make much sense).

Comment: Do you know about rings?

Comment: No. I have an econometrics and statistics background. I've done lots of different undergraduate and postgraduate mathematics subjects. I studied advanced linear algebra but I have not studied rings.

Comment: I've been told to look into at the Wikipedia article for "Unique factorization domain" - but I'd appreciate further advice.

Comment: I see, I don't have the time to write an answer right now, but generally "prime numbers" are with respect to the number system you are working in - so prime numbers make sense in the integers, but prime numbers in the rationals don't make sense, even though the integers are contained in the rationals. These number systems are called rings, and usually matrices form a ring, called a [matrix ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_ring). So what you want are the [prime elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element) of a matrix ring.

Comment: However, I should note that prime elements really only make sense in the case that your ring has commutative multiplication. Most matrix rings don't have commutative multiplication, though.

Comment: Well if you represent a Rubix cube operation as a matrix, then you wouldn't have to deal with irrational numbers... Also note that Rubix cube operations are not commutative

Comment: I suspect that the abstract mathematics you are trying to invent is an application of group theory, not ring theory. Search _group theory rubik cube_ and you'll find several links. Here's one: http://www.math.harvard.edu/~jjchen/docs/Group%20Theory%20and%20the%20Rubik%27s%20Cube.pdf

Comment: @Christian on a more fundamental note: finding a scheme to represent Rubik manipulations with matrices is called finding a [representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory) of the [Rubik's cube group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik%27s_Cube_group)

Comment: @EthanBolker You beat me to it, but yeah, reading the edited question, it seems group theory is really the right tool for this.

Comment: @Juan and Ethan - thank you for your advice. I'm going to read the links provided and have a crack at a solution. Eventually, I'd implement a solution in the Python programming language as a check to see if this can work. But I suspect I'll hit a roadblock when trying to decompose a "prime matrix" since prime number factorisation is already known to be a very difficult endeavour. However, it's still worth a crack.

Comment: See https://www.gap-system.org/Doc/Examples/rubik.html

Comment: One most elementary manipulation is e.g. turning one row to the left. But even this one can be decomposed, i.e. three rotations to the right. How to define a _prime_ manipulation_ in this context ?

Comment: If you want to play with primes in another context then look at the Gaussian Integers.  These are complex numbers whose real and imaginary parts are both integers.  They are amusingly different.  $10 = (3 + i) (3 - i)$ so, does unique factorisation still apply.

Answer (score 0):

One peculiar connection between primes and matrix products is through the definition of a so called *dynamical zeta function* . I am not sure this is what you are looking for, but it may give you some ideas. Here is an explicit application to products of matrices https://arxiv.org/abs/chao-dyn/9301001